# Chinese Evergreen Bloom black dots

Tags: houseplants, flowers, pests

Do you know what is causing the black dots in this bloom?

Some concerns - could it be infestation or mold? Is there something (that isn't this plant!) incubating-growing inside?

Since bringing this plant home, I have noticed a number (though not too many yet?) of small black flies.

[image]

Comment: The small black flies must be [fungus gnats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungus_gnat) they are harmless to the plant but very annoying to us. They like wet soil, where they could lay there eggs. The black dots are not related to them I think.